# How to enable auto watch angularJs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm beginner with angularJs and have, as i think, simple problem with whatching changes in my `$scope`.

I have an object `$scope.tasks` which i received from server. It looks like:

```
{
 2: {id: 2, name: 'name1', user: 3},
 3: {id: 3, name: 'name2', user: 1},
 4: {id: 4, name: 'name3', user: 4},
}
```

also i have a function which update user in task:

```
$scope.managePlannedIterationTask = function(taskId, userId) {
    var data = {
       'taskId' : taskId,
       'userId' : userId
    };
    $http.post("url", data).success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.tasks[taskId].user = userId; //#1
    });
};
```

also i have custom function `$scope.test();`
this function must to be executed after every change of user in tasks, for example after update query and updating at //#1

I tried to use for this goal $watch and $watchCollection:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('tasks', function () {
    $scope.test();
})
```

But this doesn't help. And now i must to insert `$scope.test()` in all places when i'm update my $scope.tasks. It's very sad.
How can i do it automatically?

Comment: When do you register the watch and how are you triggering changes?

Comment: @DavidL I register watch in the end of my controller and trigger change with ng-change in select.

Comment: That's your problem.  Register it at the beginning.  If you register it at the end, there's a reasonable chance it won't register until any interaction it would be watching has already passed.  And finally, this might be indicative of a design smell.  You might want to consider a callback-style approach instead.

Comment: @DavidL I moved my watcher to the begin of controller. Same result. Watcher doesn't work

Comment: What you've provided so far is too little to tell you WHY it isn't working for certain.  A plunkr or fiddle demonstrating the behavior would be helpful.

Comment: @Neversmile I'd not recommend you with your current approach..as watcher introduces a dirty checking inside controller. I think below answer would help you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using watch isn't be good practice to have it in code. I'd say that have an call to `test` method when you `update` call gets succeeded.

And inside a `success` callback of `post` call do make an another call to get updated `tasks` list to make your `view` data properly in sync with server data. Currently  you are updating data on client side itself for particular record, that doesn't make sense in data-centric application which is widely used by multiple users. If suppose you have `1000` users which are accessing this application, and while you are updating any record, other users also has `updated/added` any record on the same page. So that will add inconsistent behavivor inside application. So that's why I'm suggesting you to make one more ajax again to fetch data & to keep your application to look more consistent and accurate. Making an one more ajax call wouldn't take `100ms`, which is less cost paid for good reason.

**Code**

```
$scope.managePlannedIterationTask = function(taskId, userId) {
    var data = {
       'taskId' : taskId,
       'userId' : userId
    };
    $http.post("url", data).then(function(response) {
        var data = response.data;
        $scope.getTasks();
        $scope.test();
    });
};

$scope.getTasks = function(){
   $http.get('getTasksUrl').then(function(response){
      $scope.tasks = response.data;
   });
}
```

Comment: I know that using $watch could lead to performance issues and some sort of bad practice.. but why you say it is a "bad practice" ? I don't think it is always a bad practice

Comment: @PankajParkar Yes, i'm agree with you. I show my code schematically and very simple. I'm updating my tasks with  `$scope.tasks[taskId].user = userId;`  if query is success. In your example i dont like to get all tasks again if i change only one user in task. I think that is not justified

Comment: @Gonzalo.- because you know that watcher good gonna be watch that expression in each digest cycle.. an suppose you have big collection object which has `deep` watcher, so that will mess up and slow down your application performance.. therefore try to avoid usage of watcher while designing application.. personally I recommend that way..

Comment: @Neversmile by updating data on client side doesn't make sense, if suppose you have `1000` users which are accessing this application, and while you are updating any record, suppose other user also has updated/added any data on page. so that would mess up.. so that's why I'm suggesting you to make an ajax again to fetch data.. and this how data-centric application work.. making an one more ajax of `100ms` is must need to happen to make your application to look more consistent and accurate

Comment: @Neversmile I think now you are clear, why I'm suggesting to make an another call.. I updated answer with the same content

Comment: @PankajParkar sounds nice. Now i understand your position. Thanks i will try to use it, but is it possible to execute `$scope.test()` after change of `$scope.tasks` automatically?)

Comment: @PankajParkar yes yes, now i'm clear. But what about case if data is not important and i'm just change it and want to execute $scope.test() after change and it not require query.

Comment: @Neversmile then I'd say that put it inside `getTasks` function success calback..then that would be great.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a directive with watcher and put on models which you want to be watched. But if I understood you correctly you need to update data on your page after successful post request, you can achieve this by firing get request, after successful post, or at worse case scenario you can use route or state reload depending on which router you use.